# App keeps crashing. Any ideas?

Tags: android

Anytime I try to use my nexus as a test device the app crashes and I see this error.  I'm not really sure where could be the issue.
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.delta.bartalk, PID: 13668
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.delta.bartalk/com.delta.bartalk.BartalkActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020000
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020000
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1266)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:785)
                      at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:403)
                      at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.setIcon(ActionBarView.java:684)
                      at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setIcon(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:738)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setDefaultIcon(PhoneWindow.java:1646)
                      at android.app.Activity.initWindowDecorActionBar(Activity.java:2131)
                      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2146)
                      at com.delta.bartalk.BartalkActivity.onCreate(BartalkActivity.java:64)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

/* This is the beginning of activity_bartalk.xml I'm not quite sure is this is where the error could be */

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".BartalkActivity">

    <!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc. -->
    <com.delta.bartalk.AutoResizeTextView
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:textColor="#bc7ff6"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textSize="600sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/bartalk" />

    <!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows. -->
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
            style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/black_overlay"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent">

            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_text"
                style="?metaButtonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"``
                android:hint="@string/what_do_you_want_to_say" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Hello to you too. Please at least describe what were you doing before the crash happened.

Comment: show your code! Based on logcat you don't have resource (ID #0x7f020000) that you need in your oncreate method of BartalkActivity. That is all we can read from this

Comment: `Resources$NotFoundException`... Show  your code and Gradle file in a [mcve]

Comment: Can you share your layout source code? Seems like you declared resources wrong.

Comment: The activity.xml has been added.  please let me know if you think you need more.

Answer (score 2):

I think one of you resource ID's is actually missing, this may be a string in the strings.xml file, dimen.xml file, drawable, image.

This is what it seems like from looking at the fourth line of the stacktrace:

```
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020000 at
```

Please check if everything is accounted for specially for the XML file of that particular activity.

Sorry but looking from the stack trace now after being edited I can actually see it is crashing due to a missing Drawable. Check the drawable for the ActionBar please.

Comment: Should not speculate until OP has delivered enough information to justify an answer.

Comment: @MuratK. yes, but he/she has given the stack trace which you can actually analyse and find what was messing the code up. But you are right nonetheless!